# Unable to run linpack on head node of cluster

Tags: pi-4, linux, raspbian-buster, cluster

I recently set up my own home cluster - 4 units of raspberry pi. But I am having problems trying to benchmark all 4 units using Linpack

One node is the head node called rpislave1, it connects to the Internet and my local wifi network using the wlan0 interface while it uses the eth0 on it to connect to the internal LAN that is the cluster.

The other 3 nodes are rpislave2,rpislave3 and rpislave4. Each are connected to the head node - rpislave1 and get their Internet access through rpislave1. To make things simple,these 3 nodes network boot off a flash drive connected to rpislave1.

All units have been allocated their own IP address using their mac address through dhcp.

Here is the /etc/hosts file for the head node

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1 cluster

192.168.50.1    rpislave1 cluster
192.168.50.11   rpislave2
192.168.50.12   rpislave3
192.168.50.13   rpislave4
```

All units can be accessed via ssh without passwords from rpislave1 and share a NFS drive at /sharezone - which is connected to a thumbdrive mounted on rpislave1.

I am pretty happy with the learning experience and decided to benchmark the total processing of the cluster -rpislave1, rpislave2, rpislave3, and rpislave4 using HPL or linpack https://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/

I started off installing OpenMPI on the head node -rpislave1.

and it worked on its own clocking at 15 GFlops - nothing to boast about of course but it was fun.
I then proceed to set up linpack and openmpi on rpislave2 and did a standalone test and so on with the remaining units - rpislave3 and rpislave4.

So I decided to try and run it across 2 nodes - rpislave1 and rpislave2.

Here is the HPL.dat I am using for 2 nodes but I don't think the issue is the HPL.dat I am using.

```
HPLinpack benchmark input file
Innovative Computing Laboratory, University of Tennessee
HPL.out      output file name (if any) 
6            device out (6=stdout,7=stderr,file)
1            # of problems sizes (N)
40704         Ns
1            # of NBs
192           NBs
0            PMAP process mapping (0=Row-,1=Column-major)
1            # of process grids (P x Q)
2            Ps
4            Qs
16.0         threshold
1            # of panel fact
2            PFACTs (0=left, 1=Crout, 2=Right)
1            # of recursive stopping criterium
4            NBMINs (>= 1)
1            # of panels in recursion
2            NDIVs
1            # of recursive panel fact.
1            RFACTs (0=left, 1=Crout, 2=Right)
1            # of broadcast
1            BCASTs (0=1rg,1=1rM,2=2rg,3=2rM,4=Lng,5=LnM)
1            # of lookahead depth
1            DEPTHs (>=0)
2            SWAP (0=bin-exch,1=long,2=mix)
64           swapping threshold
0            L1 in (0=transposed,1=no-transposed) form
0            U  in (0=transposed,1=no-transposed) form
1            Equilibration (0=no,1=yes)
8            memory alignment in double (> 0)
##### This line (no. 32) is ignored (it serves as a separator). ######
0                               Number of additional problem sizes for PTRANS
1200 10000 30000                values of N
0                               number of additional blocking sizes for PTRANS
40 9 8 13 13 20 16 32 64        values of NB
```

Even make a host file to use with it

```
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/hpl $ cat host_file
rpislave1 slots=4
rpislave2 slots=4
```

Here is the command I used:

```
 time mpirun -hostfile host_file -np 8 /sharezone/xhpl/bin/xhpl
```

But the output I got was this

```
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/hpl $ time mpirun -hostfile host_file -np 8 /sharezone/xhpl/bin/xhpl
================================================================================
HPLinpack 2.3  --  High-Performance Linpack benchmark  --   December 2, 2018
Written by A. Petitet and R. Clint Whaley,  Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Piotr Luszczek, Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Julien Langou, University of Colorado Denver
================================================================================

An explanation of the input/output parameters follows:
T/V    : Wall time / encoded variant.
N      : The order of the coefficient matrix A.
NB     : The partitioning blocking factor.
P      : The number of process rows.
Q      : The number of process columns.
Time   : Time in seconds to solve the linear system.
Gflops : Rate of execution for solving the linear system.

The following parameter values will be used:

N      :   40704
NB     :     192
PMAP   : Row-major process mapping
P      :       2
Q      :       4
PFACT  :   Right
NBMIN  :       4
NDIV   :       2
RFACT  :   Crout
BCAST  :  1ringM
DEPTH  :       1
SWAP   : Mix (threshold = 64)
L1     : transposed form
U      : transposed form
EQUIL  : yes
ALIGN  : 8 double precision words

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- The matrix A is randomly generated for each test.
- The following scaled residual check will be computed:
      ||Ax-b||_oo / ( eps * ( || x ||_oo * || A ||_oo + || b ||_oo ) * N )
- The relative machine precision (eps) is taken to be               1.110223e-16
- Computational tests pass if scaled residuals are less than                16.0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open MPI detected an inbound MPI TCP connection request from a peer
that appears to be part of this MPI job (i.e., it identified itself as
part of this Open MPI job), but it is from an IP address that is
unexpected.  This is highly unusual.

The inbound connection has been dropped, and the peer should simply
try again with a different IP interface (i.e., the job should
hopefully be able to continue).

  Local host:          rpislave2
  Local PID:           1574
  Peer hostname:       rpislave1 ([[58941,1],2])
  Source IP of socket: 192.168.50.1
  Known IPs of peer:
        169.254.131.47
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no idea what is causing this issue but I have noticed if run the linpack test on rpislave2, rpislave3 or rpislave4 or any sort of combination of 2, it would work without issue.

It is as it I cannot run on the head node rpislave1.

I have been looking around for days trying all sorts of steps, I suspect the open MPI is accessing the wlan0 I have on the head node to connect to the local wifi network so I tried to use "--mca btl_tcp_if_exclude wlan0" or any sort of mca option but nothing worked. I even went through the github issues but all seem to have been fixed and I should have the latest patches. Here is the openmpi versions I have

```
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/hpl $ sudo apt install openmpi-bin openmpi-common libopenmpi3 libopenmpi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libopenmpi-dev is already the newest version (4.1.0-10).
libopenmpi3 is already the newest version (4.1.0-10).
openmpi-bin is already the newest version (4.1.0-10).
openmpi-common is already the newest version (4.1.0-10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/hpl $
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the "Open MPI detected an inbound MPI TCP connection request from a peer
that appears to be part of this MPI job " error? I suspect it maybe related to the wlan0 interface since it shows this

```
 Known IPs of peer:
        169.254.131.47
```

a traceroute shows this result

```
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/hpl $ traceroute 169.254.131.47
traceroute to 169.254.131.47 (169.254.131.47), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  rpislave1.local (169.254.131.47)  0.192 ms  0.107 ms  0.096 ms
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/hpl $
```

Here is the ifconfig for rpislave1/head node

```
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/hpl $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.50.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255
        inet6 fe80::d314:681c:2e82:d5bc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:1d:92:15  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 962575  bytes 911745808 (869.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 590397  bytes 382892062 (365.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3831  bytes 488990 (477.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3831  bytes 488990 (477.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.101.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.101.255
        inet6 2001:f40:950:b164:806e:1571:b836:23a4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::1636:9990:bd05:dd05  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:1d:92:16  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 44632  bytes 12764596 (12.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 74151  bytes 13143926 (12.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

user@rpislave1:/sharezone/hpl $
```

I would really appreciate any help on solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem and fixed it.

I discovered something was giving eth0 on rpislave1 2 IP addresses - 192.168.50.1 (this is from my DHCP server I setup on rpislave1) and another one 169.254.131.47 - this is the one that is causing Open MPI to screw up during mpirun. The question - what process was it? Because rpislave1 is the DHCP server for the internal network for all the raspberry pi units ( for the range 192.168.50.0/24), and it was also the connection to the outside world, I had thought it was net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 and iptables - nope, did some testing. No effect at all.

I then researched on why would the raspberry pi have 2 ip addresses on the same network interface and I found dhcpcd.service.

```
user@rpislave1:/etc $ sudo systemctl status  dhcpcd.service
● dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
             └─wait.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-07-28 16:22:45 +08; 16min ago
       Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)
    Process: 473 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd -w -q (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 8755)
        CPU: 685ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
             ├─564 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
             └─765 dhcpcd: [master] [ip4] [ip6]

Jul 28 16:22:42 rpislave1 dhcpcd[473]: eth0: probing for an IPv4LL address
Jul 28 16:22:45 rpislave1 dhcpcd[473]: forked to background, child pid 765
Jul 28 16:22:45 rpislave1 systemd[1]: Started DHCP Client Daemon.
Jul 28 16:22:45 rpislave1 dhcpcd[765]: wlan0: leased 192.168.101.15 for 259200 seconds
Jul 28 16:22:45 rpislave1 dhcpcd[765]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.101.0/24
Jul 28 16:22:45 rpislave1 dhcpcd[765]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.101.1
Jul 28 16:22:47 rpislave1 dhcpcd[765]: eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.131.47
Jul 28 16:22:47 rpislave1 dhcpcd[765]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Jul 28 16:22:50 rpislave1 dhcpcd[765]: eth0: offered 192.168.50.1 from 192.168.50.1
Jul 28 16:22:51 rpislave1 dhcpcd[765]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

Found the service that was assigning IPv4LL to itself before sending the DHCP request (which incidentally was on the same unit). This IPv4LL set the IP address and the route before it got offered the IP address from the DHCP server running on the same server. But it seemed it didn't remove the route for 169.254.0.0/16 (I suspect this is being reused for rpislave.local but that is irrevelent for my purposes).

Looking into dhcpcd.service I found this option

```
Local Link configuration
If dhcpcd failed to obtain a lease, it probes for a valid IPv4LL address (aka ZeroConf, aka APIPA). Once obtained it restarts the process of looking for a DHCP server to get a proper address.

When using IPv4LL, dhcpcd nearly always succeeds and returns an exit code of 0. In the rare case it fails, it normally means that there is a reverse ARP proxy installed which always defeats IPv4LL probing. To disable this behaviour, you can use the -L, --noipv4ll option.
```

So editted the wait.conf file in /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d - all this details can be found in the status code above.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd -w -q --noipv4ll
```

reboot and checked dhcpcd again

```
user@rpislave1:/etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d $ sudo systemctl status  dhcpcd.service
● dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
             └─wait.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-07-28 16:44:15 +08; 3min 17s ago
       Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)
    Process: 472 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd -w -q --noipv4ll (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 8755)
        CPU: 619ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
             ├─568 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
             └─775 dhcpcd: [master] [ip4] [ip6]

Jul 28 16:44:10 rpislave1 dhcpcd[472]: wlan0: adding route to 2001:f40:950:b164::/64
Jul 28 16:44:10 rpislave1 dhcpcd[472]: wlan0: requesting DHCPv6 information
Jul 28 16:44:10 rpislave1 dhcpcd[472]: wlan0: adding default route via fe80::101
Jul 28 16:44:15 rpislave1 dhcpcd[472]: wlan0: leased 192.168.101.15 for 259200 seconds
Jul 28 16:44:15 rpislave1 dhcpcd[472]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.101.0/24
Jul 28 16:44:15 rpislave1 dhcpcd[472]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.101.1
Jul 28 16:44:15 rpislave1 dhcpcd[472]: forked to background, child pid 775
Jul 28 16:44:15 rpislave1 systemd[1]: Started DHCP Client Daemon.
Jul 28 16:44:19 rpislave1 dhcpcd[775]: eth0: offered 192.168.50.1 from 192.168.50.1
Jul 28 16:44:21 rpislave1 dhcpcd[775]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
user@rpislave1:/etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d $
```

And the route for "eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.131.47" was not being set at all.

So I went about testing the whole cluster

```
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/ClusterProcessing/HPL $  time mpirun -hostfile ../host_file -np 16 /sharezone/xhpl/bin/xhpl |tee HPL.log
================================================================================
HPLinpack 2.3  --  High-Performance Linpack benchmark  --   December 2, 2018
Written by A. Petitet and R. Clint Whaley,  Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Piotr Luszczek, Innovative Computing Laboratory, UTK
Modified by Julien Langou, University of Colorado Denver
================================================================================

An explanation of the input/output parameters follows:
T/V    : Wall time / encoded variant.
N      : The order of the coefficient matrix A.
NB     : The partitioning blocking factor.
P      : The number of process rows.
Q      : The number of process columns.
Time   : Time in seconds to solve the linear system.
Gflops : Rate of execution for solving the linear system.

The following parameter values will be used:

N      :   57600
NB     :     192
PMAP   : Row-major process mapping
P      :       4
Q      :       4
PFACT  :   Right
NBMIN  :       4
NDIV   :       2
RFACT  :   Crout
BCAST  :  1ringM
DEPTH  :       1
SWAP   : Mix (threshold = 64)
L1     : transposed form
U      : transposed form
EQUIL  : yes
ALIGN  : 8 double precision words

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- The matrix A is randomly generated for each test.
- The following scaled residual check will be computed:
      ||Ax-b||_oo / ( eps * ( || x ||_oo * || A ||_oo + || b ||_oo ) * N )
- The relative machine precision (eps) is taken to be               1.110223e-16
- Computational tests pass if scaled residuals are less than                16.0

================================================================================
T/V                N    NB     P     Q               Time                 Gflops
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WR11C2R4       57600   192     4     4            2558.14             4.9804e+01
HPL_pdgesv() start time Fri Jul 28 16:55:04 2023

HPL_pdgesv() end time   Fri Jul 28 17:37:42 2023

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
||Ax-b||_oo/(eps*(||A||_oo*||x||_oo+||b||_oo)*N)=   3.39874554e-03 ...... PASSED
================================================================================

Finished      1 tests with the following results:
              1 tests completed and passed residual checks,
              0 tests completed and failed residual checks,
              0 tests skipped because of illegal input values.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End of Tests.
================================================================================
[rpislave4:00682] PMIX ERROR: NO-PERMISSIONS in file ../../../../../../src/mca/common/dstore/dstore_base.c at line 237
[rpislave3:00688] PMIX ERROR: NO-PERMISSIONS in file ../../../../../../src/mca/common/dstore/dstore_base.c at line 237
[rpislave2:00696] PMIX ERROR: NO-PERMISSIONS in file ../../../../../../src/mca/common/dstore/dstore_base.c at line 237

real    43m33.445s
user    141m36.616s
sys     28m21.561s
user@rpislave1:/sharezone/ClusterProcessing/HPL $
```

And it works~! Now I can do a full benchmark of all 4 units inclusive of the head~!